# System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I got this error while Parse an string to XDocument after edit and save it. But anyone can help me locate error position - The Line 1, position 10475. How can i get that position ???

> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML
>   declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space
>   characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 10475.

```
if (storage.FileExists("APPSDATA.xml"))
{
  var reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("APPSDATA.xml", FileMode.Open, storage));

  string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
  var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);//error here 
  reader.Close();
```

The XML is big, this is jus a part of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Ungdungs>
  <Ungdung>
    <Name>HERE City Lens</Name>
    <Id>b0a0ac22-cf9e-45ba-8120-815450e2fd71</Id>
    <Path>/Icon/herecitylens.png</Path>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Category>HERE</Category>
    <Date>Uknown</Date>
  </Ungdung>
  <Ungdung>
    <Name>HERE Transit</Name>
    <Id>adfdad16-b54a-4ec3-b11e-66bd691be4e6</Id>
    <Path>/Icon/heretransit.png</Path>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Category>HERE</Category>
    <Date>Uknown</Date>
  </Ungdung>
```

Comment: @BuiAkinori As `XDocument` says, there is something wrong in your xml. So without seeing it I can only say, open your xml with an editor goto to the location xDocument reports and see what is wrong.

Comment: @l4V how to get to that poisition :(  Line 1, position 10475

Comment: @BuiAkinori `how to get to that poisition`? Really? How to you plan to finish your code, if you get stuck in every minor problem.

Comment: Do you have anything before the `<?xml` ?

Comment: ok i will use netbean to validate it :(

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov No :(

Comment: @BuiAkinori What about whitespaces ? Do you have any (before the `<?xml`) ?

Comment: I already check that there's nothing before that, I even tried trim

Comment: @BuiAkinori Check if you have `<?xml` repeated anywhere else in the document (that's illegal, so it won't be valid). You're saying it's long, search it and see if you have it somewhere down the lines

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov, holy cow, u're right, i found another <?xml :( tks so much. Answer it so i can mark it as answer :)

Comment: Not sure why you received so may downvotes, it's a legitimate question IMHO. Cheers.

Comment: Haha, I dont care about that, that point or vote doesn't matter to me :D as long as I get the right answer :D

Comment: @BuiAkinori Then Why did create a new account http://stackoverflow.com/users/2735373/bui-minh-dc

Comment: @I4V: because yesterday, this account had asked 6 questions, i couln't ask more so I created new acc to do that :D Dont try to mock me dude :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your `<?xml` tag is the first thing in the document (and that it doesn't have anything before that, this includes whitespace).
You can have `<?xml` only once per document, so if you have a large chunk of XML and you have this tag repeated somewhere down the lines your document won't be valid.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was related to the byte order mark - BOM. I opened the file in Notepad++ selected encoding "encode in UTF-8 without BOM" and was then able to see the annoying charater and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur if you previously saved the xml file with the boolean 'append = true'.
Make if 'false', it should work.