# Delete a specific XML element and its child elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

Say I have this XML File:

```
<Stops>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1022</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1053</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test1045</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
</Stops>
```

I want to delete the entire  node where the ID is equal to a value.

So e.g. deleting the  node with 1022 should give:

```
<Stops>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1053</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test1045</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
</Stops>
```

The code I've been trying so far (C# in Windows Phone). It seems to malform and make the XML unreadable. I don't know where I'm going wrong...

```
        using (isoStore)
        {
            XDocument doc;
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(StopFileName, FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream, LoadOptions.None);
                doc.Descendants("Stop")
                      .Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == "1022").Remove();

                doc.Save(isoStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you mean by malform? Does the xml remain valid after removal?

Comment: The XML does appear to work looking at the locals... but when I reload the XML file to read, it gives an XMLException..  Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it

Comment: Check how to do that [here][1] and [here][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919645/how-to-delete-node-from-xml-file-using-c-sharp
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229330/deleting-specific-node-in-xml

Comment: Is my LINQ code right though? It appears to be for me... I'm wondering if its an issue with IsolatedStorage

Comment: @ForeverLearning use this link regarding your error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546494/system-xml-xmlexception-unexpected-xml-declaration-the-xml-declaration-must-be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is reading and saving using the same stream.

If you look at your own code you load the xml from your file:

```
doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream, LoadOptions.None);
```

And then save to the same stream:

```
doc.Save(isoStream);
```

So you end up with an XML File looking like this

```
<Stops>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1022</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1053</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test1045</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
</Stops>
<Stops>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1053</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test1045</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
</Stops>
```

And having 2 root elements would indeed cause a "Unexpected XML declaration"

I would change your code so first you read the file, and then creates a new file / overwrites an existing file.

```
        using (isoStore)
        {
            XDocument doc;
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(StopFileName, FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream, LoadOptions.None);
            }

            doc.Descendants("Stop")
                      .Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == "1022").Remove();

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(StopFileName, FileMode.Create, isoStore))
            {
                doc.Save(isoStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just checked this, YES! this is what is happening... what do I need to change to fix it? Thankyou!

Comment: Instead of appending to the same file, overwrite it or create a new file.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it! Thanks for the help! I thought it was an XML issue... never realised the IsolatedStorage just appended to the xml

Comment: I added the solution as code, in case others need it.